# In my application spinner is not working in IE 10 and IE 11. In chrome its working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Js file:

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';
    require('widgets-path/abstract/abstractClearablePresenter');
    var view = require('widgets-path/abstract/abstractView');
    var spinnerTemplate = require('hbs!widgets-path/loading/templates/spinner');

    $.widget('els.loading', $.els.abstractClearablePresenter, {
        _create: function () {
            this.element = $('#loadingWidget');
            this.element.html(spinnerTemplate());
            this._super(view, {});

            this._subscribeOnEvent('allWidgetsLoaded', this._afterLoaded);
            this._subscribeOnEvent('showLoading', this._showSpinner);
            this._subscribeOnEvent('hideLoading', this._hideSpinner);
        },

        _afterLoaded: function () {
            this.element.addClass('afterLoaded');
        },

        _showSpinner: function () {
            this.element.show();
        },

        _hideSpinner: function () {
            this._view.hide();
        }
    });
    return $.els.loading();
});
```

HI team,

I have one issue in my application, 
scenario:
when your page is loading time spinner gif is coming until page load, in chrome its working fine. But in IE 10 and IE 11 is not working.

they call hbs and js

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<img src="./common/img/loading.gif"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (!IE)|(gte IE 10)]>-->

<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: can you provide your html page